# How to prove that prime $q \neq p$ isn't ramified in $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I want to show that there is only one $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of the field of rational numbers - $\mathbb{Q}$. The cyclotomic one.

For that I need to show that if the field $\mathbb{K}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then extension $\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q}$ is unramified in any prime number $q \neq p$.

I have found two different proof of this fact, but I fail to understand the ending of both of them. One is in the book "L. C. Washington - Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields", on page 265 - Proposition 13.2, and the other one is in the article "On $\Gamma$-extensions of algebraic number fields. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 65 (1959), 183-226." of Kenkichi Iwasawa, Lemma 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an abelian extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ then (Kronecker Weber) $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ is a quotient of $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty})/\Bbb{Q}) = \hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times$.

> We assume $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q}) \cong \Bbb{Z}_p$ as **profinite topological groups**

$Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ is torsion free thus the kernel of $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty) / \Bbb{Q}) \to Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ contains the profinite completion of $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty) / \Bbb{Q})_{tors} = \hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors} = \prod_q'(\Bbb{Z}_q^\times)_{tors}$ so that $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ is a quotient of $$ \hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times/\overline{\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors} } =  \prod_q \Bbb{Z}_q^\times/(\Bbb{Z}_q^\times)_{tors}=(1+4\Bbb{Z}_2)\prod_{q\ne 2}(1+q\Bbb{Z}_q)$$
(think to the RHS not as a subgroup but as a quotient of $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times$)

$Gal(K/\Bbb{Q}) \cong \Bbb{Z}_p$ tells us $K = \bigcup_n K_n$ where $Gal(K_n/\Bbb{Q}) \cong \Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z}$,

Since $Gal(K_n/\Bbb{Q})$ is of order $p^n$ we obtain that $K_n$ is fixed by $$(\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times/\overline{\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors} } )^{p^n}=(1+4\Bbb{Z}_2)^{p^n}\prod_{q\ne 2}(1+q\Bbb{Z}_q)^{p^n}= (1+p^{n+1}\Bbb{Z}_p) (1+4\Bbb{Z}_2) \prod_{q\ne 2,p}(1+q\Bbb{Z}_q)$$ and hence $K= \bigcup_n K_n$ is fixed by $$\bigcap_n (\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times/\overline{\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors} } )^{p^n}=(1+4\Bbb{Z}_2) \prod_{q\ne 2,p}(1+q\Bbb{Z}_q)=Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_\infty)/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})^{\langle \omega_{p-1}\rangle})$$ Whence $ K $ is a subfield of $ \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})^{\langle \omega_{p-1}\rangle}$ and since the later is a $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension, its subfields are finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ and hence $$K=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})^{\langle \omega_{p-1}\rangle}$$

Comment: Can you, please, explain in greater detail why:

1. $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times/\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors} =\Bbb{Z}_2^\times/\langle \omega_{2,2}\rangle\prod_{q/2} \Bbb{Z}_q^\times/\langle \omega_{q,q-1} \rangle=(1+4\Bbb{Z}_2) \prod_{q\ne 2} (1+q \Bbb{Z}_q)$?

2. $H_n = Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty})^{\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors} }/K_n)$ is of index $p^n$ in $ \hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times/\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors} $?

3. how the conclusion follows from that?

Comment: 1. is a basic fact about $p$-adic and profinite integers, you need to tell where you are stuck in defining / understanding them. 2. $Z/p^nZ = Gal(K_n/Q) = Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty})^{\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors} }/Q) /Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{\infty})^{\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors}}/K_n)=(\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times/\hat{\Bbb{Z}}^\times_{tors})/H_n$. The conclusion is that $K_n$ and $K$ are fixed by $Gal(Q(\zeta_\infty)/Q(i,\zeta_{p^\infty}))$ thus are contained in $Q(i,\zeta_{p^\infty}))$ whose Galois group is $1+pZ_p\times $ a finite group. $1+pZ_p\cong Z_p$ (one is multiplicative group the other additive)

Comment: I cleant a few details

Comment: Now is everything clear, thank you a lot! :-)

Comment: @jankri See http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,1863178,1865562#msg-1865562 for a short argument of why any $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ must be unramified outside of $p$

Comment: great! Thank you a lot for your effort!